# Como ler o html de uma pagina que só carrega ao abrir no navegador em GOLANG

Tags: golang

Estou tentando ler o HTML da seguinte página (https://www.lojacorpoperfeito.com.br/pesquisa/?busca=suplemento&indice=0/), mas o problema é que o HTML dela só é carregado quando é aberto no navegador, ao entrar nela e apertar Ctrl + U você perceberá que há somente o javascript que carrega os produtos, mas no HTML ela fica como deveria ser para ser lida.

Atualmente estou abrindo as páginas com o "goquery".

Comment: Mostra o que você já tentou, pode ajudar...

Comment: tentei o de sempre, procurar por tags da página pra tentar ler o conteudo href, mas a página aberta no navegador é diferete da aberta pelo GO, assim não acho nenhuma tag que procuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você mesmo já responde a sua pergunta. Você diz "ao entrar nela e apertar Ctrl + U você perceberá que há somente o javascript que carrega os produtos".

O Golang, por padrão, não possui nenhum motor de Javascript e num contexto geral não há nenhum sentido em ter. Você provavelmente está obtendo o conteúdo da página usando a biblioteca de `http`, ela vai apenas obter o conteúdo daquela página, ou seja o mesmo HTML que você está vendo no CTRL + U. Se nele conter algum `<img>`, `<script>` (...) será insignificante, o Golang não vai carregar esses conteúdos, exceto se você usar algum biblioteca que faça isso (algum "navegador em golang" ou integre ele à algum outro webdriver...).

---

A solução mais prática é ver dá onde o conteúdo é obtido. Se o elemento é dinamicamente criado ele vem de algum lugar, então basta achar esta fonte.

A maneira mais prática é indo no Console (F12 ou CTRL + SHIFT + I) e então em "Network" e selecionar "XHR", neste caso você vai ver que existe uma requisição para:

```
https://busca.saudifitness.com.br/externalapp/?busca=SeuTermoBuscado&full=true&idapp=1
```

Ele retorna um JSON com os produto, ele é o conteúdo que o JS usa para exibir os elementos na página. Pronto. Ao invés de requisitar a outra página (que contem o JS), simplesmente requisite a página que já tem as informações...

Comment: foi exatamente o que fiz amigo, muito obrigado por me lembrar da pergunta, vou dar como correto mesmo ja tendo descoberto antes pois é exatamente isso, obrigado